# Performance impact on Android Annotations

Tags: android, annotations, lint

are there any performance impact on an App for using  Code Inspection Annotations?

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html

Does it impact on the final App or these annotations are discarded when the project is built?

Comment: I believe these annotations are discarded when the project is build. However, you need to remove the annotation library from final apk.

Comment: if you remove the annotation library from the final release, you'll have to remove also all the a Annotations and imports. is that what you mean?

Comment: You make sense but I don't think it is possible. Let me do some more work on it.

Comment: thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

I see when i have an annotationed method like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
}
```

And compile and decompile it using apkmanager there is no mention of that annotation inside decompiled smali code

```
.method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
.locals 1
.parameter "icicle"
.end method
```

And even if i use smali2java tools there is no annotation remain in newly java code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
}
```

So that i think annotations are only for compile process and will be removed after project is build.

Comment: Did you try with Resources Annotations?  https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#res-annotations